# return column name with closest value

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

So I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to return the name of the column which has the closet value to my query.

So this is my table:

```
--------------------------
| ID | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 |
--------------------------
| 1  | 0  | 10 | 22 | 50 |
--------------------------
```

I would like to do a query where I am searching in D1 to D4 for the closest value of 20, in this case D3

Then I would like to return D3 and the value in it.

So my answer should be:

```
------
| D3 |
------
| 22 |
------
```

Is this by any way possible?

Comment: Can your change your table design? It is not normalized

Comment: What if multiple values are closest?

Comment: can't change the table, this is what I have to work with :(

Comment: If several are closest then the smallest of them ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not easily. Since you've got those as different fields in the same record, you'll have to use very ugly queries:

```
SELECT source, val, ABS(20 - val) AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT 'd1' AS source, d1 AS val FROM foo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd2', d2 FROM foo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd3', d3 FROM foo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd4', d4 FROM foo
) AS child
ORDER BY diff DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table, which'd entirely eliminate the entire `union` business and leave only the outer parent query.

Comment: can't normalize the table. This looks like the closest here. At this point I am getting a 'syntact error, near select' but it doesn't show the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a complicated `case`:

```
select (case least(abs(d1 - 20), abs(d2 - 20), abs(d3 - 20), abs(d4 - 20))
            when abs(d1 - 20) then 'd1'
            when abs(d2 - 20) then 'd2'
            when abs(d3 - 20) then 'd3'
            when abs(d4 - 20) then 'd4'
        end)
from mytable;
```

Note:  This should have better performance than normalizing the data using `union all`.  However, as a comment on the data structure, you probably want to store the values in separate rows rather than separate columns.  Having separate columns with essentially the same values usually suggests the need for a junction table.

Comment: It seems SQLlite doesn't know 'least'

Comment: @BonifatiusK . . . The question is tagged "mysql" (as well).

Comment: I know, answer is correct but not for sqllite. I will be more clear next time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at something like http://www.techfounder.net/2009/02/02/selecting-closest-values-in-mysql/

What language are you using to echo out the data?

Comment: Why does this get a minus?

Comment: because it's not an answer. it's "go here to see an answer". link-only answers are not answers. e.g. if that link dies, then your answer becomes useless.

Comment: And answers are supposed to be answers, not questions. To ask for clarifications, use a comment.